# Cyrillic text in MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, python, unicode, monkeyrunner

I am trying to type Cyrillic text on my Android device using MonkeyRunner, but it either outputs nothing or only question mark ("?") characters.

The code:

```
print (sys.getdefaultencoding())
print (locale.getpreferredencoding())
print (sys.stdout.encoding)
```

provides following output:

```
ascii
None
Cp1251
```

I tried following methods to display the text:

```
device.type('Мой текст')  #This code type nothing
device.type(u'Мой текст') #This code type nothing
device.type(unicode('Мой текст','cp1251')) #This code type nothing
device.type(unicode('Мой текст','cp1251').encode('utf8')) #This code type nothing
device.type(u"\u0410".encode('utf8')) #This code type ??
device.type("\xe2\x98\x83".decode('utf8')) #This code type ?
```

What is the correct way to use encode/decode methods or any other way to display Cyrillic characters through `device.type()`?

Answer (score 0):

See ADBKeyBoard: https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard

device.shell("am broadcast -a ADB_INPUT_TEXT --es msg 'Серёжа'")